# Comparing many numbers to find minimum and maximum

Tags: c++, algorithm

To keep it simple lets say I have 3 whole numbers (integers) I know I can find the highest by using something like:

```
if(num1 > num2 && num1 > num3)
    cout << num1 << endl;
if(num2 > num1 && num2 > num3)
    cout << num2 << endl;
if(num3 > num1 && num3 > num2)
    cout << num3 << endl;
```

And the lowest:

```
if(num1 < num2 && num1 < num3)
    cout << num1 << endl;
if(num2 > num1 && num2 > num3)
    cout << num2 << endl;
if(num3 < num1 && num3 < num2)
    cout << num3 << endl;
```

How can I get something like this to deal with equalities like 221,111,122,121.
edit: Im trying to stay away from any prebuilt math includes as that is not the point here..

Comment: Let me just give you advice that you should rather use `else if` statement after first `if` instead of `if` all the time.

Comment: Why wouldn't it work with 221, 111, 122 and 121? Also, I think you have the operators in the second `if` of the second code sample the wrong way around.

Comment: as long as you're always dealing with just three numbers, how about replacing < with <= ?

Comment: Are you looking for `>=` greater than or equal to? (Is that what you mean by `equalities like 221,111,122,121`, that is, `num1 = 2; num2 = 2; num3 = 1`?)

Comment: Make your own math libaries then and use them. Start with `std::max`. Then `max(max(num1, num2), num3))` is your max. Should take a minute.

Comment: Indeed it would work. But it will return the wrong number. I found this out if I name them the wrong name pops out.

Comment: Work out how if should work for two, then recurse. Something like `int max(int a, int b) { if(a>b)return a; else return b;} int max(int a, int b, int c) {return max(a,max(b,c));}` Note in my case I actually pick "one" if they are equal.

Comment: A better way, if you're expanding this to large/arbitrary-length sets of numbers, is to sort and then take the first or last as needed.

Comment: @iamnotmaynard Good call, or heapify depending on your needs.

Comment: Looks like as stated above the only alternative seems to be equality and just using else to keep  unwanted repetition out. The best by far is just to store my values in a container.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should look into storing your values in a container such as `vector` (I can't tell if you will *always* have three or if you may vary in number). Then you can use `std::min_element` and `std::max_element` which are already written and tuned to find the min/max from a sequence of values.

Comment: Another fun trick, in c++11:  `std::max` and `std::min` both have overloads that use initializer lists.  This lets you do `int m = std::max({a,b,c,d})`.  In the cases where you have a fixed set of variables to compare, and don't have another use for a container.

Comment: Further, C++11 has [`std::minmax`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax) and [`std::minmax_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax_element) to give you both items with a single traversal.