# Comparing 3 number properties of an object

Tags: c++, algorithm

I wanted to know what would be the fastest and most efficient way of comparing three numerical properties of a number and determining the lowest value and the highest value.
Say I have an object with following prop

```
obj.a = 5;
obj.b = 13;
obj.c = 2;
```

Now I need to calculate the lowest value(2) and the highest value(13);

One option I have is using conditional statement thus having three conditions for checking the greatest element and three for the lowest element.Resulting in 6 conditional statements.My other option is pushing these values in a vector and then retrieving the extreme values from a sorted vector. Is there an alternative approach to this ? Any suggestions ?

Comment: is there a range for the possible numbers?

Comment: Creating and then sorting a vector is definitely not the most efficient way for comparing 3 numbers.

Comment: Extreme approach, but should work for large range of numbers: Binary search tree

Comment: I think populating a vector would be overkill. Want other opinions also

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14468542/comparing-many-numbers-to-find-minimum-and-maximum?rq=1

Comment: @ScepticalJule: the problem is quite different here. OP wants to know the most efficient way to compare a few numbers (three, in fact), not many numbers as in the other question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your Min() function for 2 variables as:

```
int Min(int x, int y)
{
    return y ^ ((x ^ y) & -(x < y));
}
```

Similarly Max for 2 variables as:

```
int Max(int x, int y)
{
    return x ^ ((x ^ y) & -(x < y));
}
```

And now call this function for your 3 variables as:

```
int max = Max(a,Max(b,c));
int min = Min(a,Min(b,c));
```

These methods are quite efficient and may be used for any number of variable comparison.

It uses the concept that

1. the XOR of a number with itself is 0
2. XOR of a number with 0 is the number itself.

Again this can be used for nested calls for N number of number comparisons.

**NOTE:** You may even replace `x<y` with `x-y>>31` (considering X to be a 32 bit signed integer).

I am very much sure that it cannot be more efficient than that for 3 numbers

Comment: But you know that this will only work for integers between 1 and 0? (x < y) returns `true` or `false`, which is being promoted to `int`, resulting in `1` or `0`. 1 is represented in binary as `...000001`, thus applying it with `&` to another number will only leave the last bit of that other number on. Thus `5 + ((10-5) & (10 > 5))` == `5 + (5 & 1)` == `5 + 1` == `6`, which is clearly not correct.

Comment: @Azzu Ohh I had forgotten the negative sign. thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Now you only need to change the `<` operators to  `>`  in `max()`.

Comment: @Azzu no this is fine.

Comment: After profiling, this answer is the fastest. This is just as fast as Keiths answer, but this can be wrapped into two functions with 3 parameters (like it would make sense to use in this case) instead of returning the result in a pair.

Comment: Quoting http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#IntegerMinOrMax:
"On some rare machines where branching is very expensive and no condition move instructions exist, the above expression might be faster than the obvious approach, r = (x < y) ? x : y, even though it involves two more instructions. (Typically, the obvious approach is best, though.)"

Answer (score 2):

If using C+11 is okay, you can just do:

```
auto result = std::minmax({a, b, c});
```

`result.first` will hold the smallest value, `result.second` the largest - here's a [live demo](http://ideone.com/jdkfln).

Comment: If we trust the STL implementers (as we should usually do), this will also be the fastest method.

Comment: This may be the fastest, but since you have the conversion to an initializer list and then the function will call std::minmax_element on that list, it is slower.

Comment: @Azzu: You may find that your compiler is fairly good at optimizing the call since it can see that the initializer list contains only a few elements.

Comment: I meant fastest for more elements. Also I should have said that I profiled all the answers. This is only around 15%~ slower than the bit fiddling though.

Answer (score 1):

A solution with no more than three compares:

```
struct Obj
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    std::pair<int,int> getMinMax() const
    {
        std::pair<int,int> minmax = a< b ? std::make_pair(a,b) : std::make_pair(b,a);
        if (c < minmax.first )
            minmax.first = c;
        else if (c > minmax.second)
            minmax.second = c;
        return minmax;
    }
};
```

Comment: After profiling, this is the fastest, on par with the bit fiddling. The bit fiddling provides the advantage that it can be two seperate functions, returning min/max respectively.

Answer (score 0):

I am giving the psudocode:

```
a[0] = obj.a
a[1] = obj.b
a[2] = obj.c
```

To get largest:

```
index = int(obj.a < obj.b)
larger = a[index]

largest = a[(larger > obj.c) ? index : 2]
```

To get the smallest:

```
index = int (obj.a > obj.b)
smaller = a[index]

smallest = a[(smaller < obj.c) ? index : 2]
```

Makes 2 + 2 comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

Once you've found that a is the minimum, you don't have to consider it for the maximum anymore. So any solution that determines min and max separately is sub-optimal.

There are 6 ways to order 3 things: abc acb bac bca cab cba. So no solution can do with less than 6 branches.

This solution has 6 branches, with at most 3 comparisons per case, so I expect it to be optimal:

```
if (obj.a < obj.b)
{
  if (obj.b < obj.c)
  {
     min = obj.a; max = obj.c;  // abc
  }
  else if (obj.c < obj.a)
  {
     min = obj.c; max = obj.b;  // cab
  }
  else
  {
     min = obj.a; max = obj.b;  // acb
  }
}
else
{
  if (obj.a < obj.c)
  {
     min = obj.b; max = obj.c;  // bac
  }
  else if (obj.c < obj.b)
  {
     min = obj.c; max = obj.a;  // cba
  }
  else
  {
     min = obj.b; max = obj.a;  // bca
  }
}
```

**EDIT**:
Apparently, this is slow. I guess it has something to do with the conditional jumps. Conditional moves are better:

Maybe this one is better, although it still has one branch:

```
if (obj.a < obj.b)
{
   min = std::min(obj.a, obj.c);
   max = std::max(obj.b, obj.c);
}
else
{
   min = std::min(obj.b, obj.c);
   max = std::max(obj.a, obj.c);
}
```

Eleminating the last branch would turn this into one of the other answers:

```
  min = std::min(std::min(obj.a, obj.b), obj.c);
  max = std::max(std::max(obj.a, obj.b), obj.c);
```

**Bottomline**: Who would have thought that the 'naive' approach would be faster than writing it all out!

Comment: Funnily enough, after profiling, this IS slower than two functions.